# OpenSearch - Cant filter an aggregated field

Tags: elasticsearch, magento2, opensearch

I'm currently working on an edited filter on magento2 (the sold_by field). The OS returns me a lot of sellers and I want to optimize the request to only gather the sellers in the current store. I indexed all my products with a list of all sellers with the format "seller-storeId", it's ok until I try to filter the request results. When I do this, it works

```
"my_filter": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "type_id": "simple"
        }
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "type_id_test": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "type_id",
            "size": 10,
            "min_doc_count": 1,
            "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
            "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
            "order": [
              {
                "_count": "desc"
              },
              {
                "_key": "asc"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
```

But when I do it with the field I am working on, it results 0 (but I have occurrences, so it should return at least 1)

The problem I identified is that `type_id` is mapped like this

```
"type_id": { - 
          "type": "keyword"
        },
```

and my field is

```
"option_text_sold_by": { -
          "type": "text",
          "fields": { -
            "untouched": { -
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          },
          "copy_to": [ -
            "search",
            "spelling"
          ],
          "analyzer": "standard",
          "fielddata": true
        },
```

I've never worked with Elastic/OpenSearch, so it's kinda hard for me. Has anyone ever faced my issue ? :(

Comment: If you use term query must use field type keyword. Provide the query with real field that have problem.

Comment: Thanks @rabbitbr , but we found a way, by doing this, it works !

"test": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "option_text_sold_by.untouched",
        "include": ".*21.*",
        "size": 10,
        "min_doc_count": 1,
        "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
        "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
        "order": [
          {
            "_count": "desc"
          },
          {
            "_key": "asc"
          }
        ]
      }
    },